# queue worker best approach (no child process spawning)

Tags: node.js, worker

Does anyone know a good nodejs library or approach for a 'never ending' worker process? The idea is to have a single, separate node instance picking up a job (row) from mysql or redis and processing it. Main point would be to have the options to send signals to the process to terminate gracefully if necessary. I'd rather use an existing library that has proven itself to be reliable. Since process spawning is way too much waste for the small jobs I intent to run (updating cache, sending emails, etc) there should be no child process spawning. Any ideas how to do this best specifically in NodeJS?